# One application for curating my bird videos?

Tags: video, catalog

I have a [trail camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_camera) pointed at some birdfeeders on my apartment's balcony. I leave it running most of the time and have about 1000x 80 MB .avi files. Obviously some are great but most are boring or repetitive.

For viewing and editing the videos, I have been using a mixture of

- VLC
- the Windows 10 "Photos" app
- the Windows 10 video editor

I also use Digikam on Ubuntu to manage my still photos

Is there a single application, on any platform, that will let me do most or all of the following? I prefer opensource.

- conveniently view the videos back to back, possibly at 1.5x or 2.0x
- delete and tag while viewing
- trim the start and end
- modify the contrast etc.
- convert .avi to something like MPEG
- edit metadata like exposure date

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the upvotes on the question. I have learned how quickly delete lots of unwanted videos in VLC. I'm still doing the trimming and color tweaking in the Windows 10 video editor.

For efficient manual review and deletion:

- [Setting default playback speed](https://superuser.com/questions/876074/how-to-change-playback-speed-steps-in-vlc-player)
- [plugin for deleting the currently playing file](https://github.com/surrim/vlc-delete). I haven't figured how to bind a hotkey yet.
- I recursively load all of the videos in a folder by right-clicking and selecting "Play with VLC media player" in Windows 10

I have experimented with a [video deduping application](https://www.video-comparer.com/). It seems like it can identify identical videos that just got saved with different names, but I haven't found it for deleting videos that are thematically similar like "woodpecker perching on top of bird feeder".

Comment: I look forward to those specifics

Comment: oh, yeah! will send tomorrow. sorry about that.